# Cannot modify items with inactive Users

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2010, infopath

I have items in a list that has been modified by a user that has now left. In Active Directory the user that left, his account is inactive.

Now when I try to modify the items modified by this user, I cannot. I get the red squiggly line under his name in the 'Modified By' Column. When I modify the item and try to save it; I get the following error:

[image: Error for Modified By while saving]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two workarounds to avoid this issue.

1. Enable again the inactive user to be able to update the list item that modified by the inactive user. once you have finished disable it again.
2. Try to update the `Modified by` field using PowerShell

**Script**

```
$web=get-SPWeb "You Web URL"
$list=$web.Lists["Your List"]
$replacedUser =$web.EnsureUser("domainName\Account")
foreach($item in $list.Items)       
{        
   if ($item["Editor"] -eq "old user") 
    {
      $item["Editor"] = $replacedUser   
      $item.update()        
    }
}        
$web.Update()        
$web.dispose()
```